# laravel, choose a selected item to be selected by default in option

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, html-select

I am using **laravel 5.4**, the "selected" option for option tag is not working.

Any suggestions please?

For example:

```
<div class="labelandinput">
   <label  >Gender:</label>
   <select name="gender"  id="gender" >
      @if ($info->gender=="male")
     <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
     @elseif($info->gender=="female")
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female" selected>Female</option>
     @endif
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: not selecting the element that is chosen to be selected like female in else condition .
it is by default set to the first option .. in this case (male option)

Comment: Could you dump `$info->gender` to see whether this does not contain female?

Comment: it contains female i checked that

Comment: Just trying to rule out side effects: how did you check which item is selected? By inspecting the source code?

Comment: yes I printed the value from the controller and the values are right

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
{!! Form::select('gender', ['male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'], 'male'); !!}
```

Check the documentation : [Doc](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html)

```
<div class="labelandinput">
  {{ Form::label('gender', 'Gender:') }}
  @if ($info->gender == "male")
    {!! Form::select('gender', ['male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'], 'male'); !!}
  @elseif ($info->gender == "female")
    {!! Form::select('gender', ['male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'], 'female'); !!}
  @endif
</div>
```

Comment: where to add this statement please?

Comment: In your blade page ? I added it in my answer.

Comment: thank you but I tried this and same problem is still there